# Filter More PHP Search Result using Dropdown box value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I have the following code i want to Filter the Search results more/ Narrow the search result in a table  using the values in drop down box. I am able to search using text box but i also want to filter more search result using drop down values

//dropdown

```
    <select name="size1" id="search" class="form-control" style=" width: 200px;font-family: Abel;font-weight: 900;font-size: 15px;color:#000; background: #fff" >
     <option value="">Select Size</option>
     <option value="val1">Val1</option>
     <option value="val2">Val2</option>
     <option value="val3">Val3</option>
 </select>
```

//textbox

```
        <label id="lbl_auto_year" for="auto_year" class="" >Narrow your Search by Man<br/>
        <input  value="" class="form-control input-sm" autocomplete="off" name="txttreadd" id="search"  style="width:200px;color:#000;background:#fff" type="text">
```

//PHP code which displays result

```
 echo'<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="dataTables-example" ><tbody>';

   $record = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY Manufacturer");
   while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($record)) {
   if($row['RC']!="" && $row['SW']!="")
     {
      if($ag=="" && $size1=="" && $size=="" && $lcc=="" && $scc=="" && $smallsw==""  && $largesw=="" && $smallrc=="" && $largerc=="" && $txtsize=="" && $small== "" && $large == "")  
     {
     }

     elseif ($row['Tread_Design']==$R1W) 
        {    
      echo "<tr>";


                        //echo "<td style=' width:300px;text-align:left; padding-left: 10px;vertical-align: middle;'>";echo $row['Manufacturer'];echo"</td>";
                        echo "<td style=' width:150px;  text-align:left; padding: 10px;vertical-align: middle;'>";echo $row['Brand_Name'];echo"</td>";
                        echo "<td style='width:110px;  text-align:left; vertical-align: middle;'>";echo $row['Tire_Size'];"</td>";
                        echo "<td style='width:100px;  text-align:left; vertical-align: middle;'>";echo $row['SW'];"</td>"; 
                        echo "<td style='width:100px; text-align:left;vertical-align: middle;'>";echo $row['OD'];"</td>";

    echo '</tr></tbody></table>';
 }
 }......
```

And Here is the JS Code which works when using textbox. How can i make it work work for dropdown

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
  var $rows = $('#dataTables-example2 tbody tr');
 $('#search').keyup(function() {
var val = $.trim($(this).val()).replace(/ +/g, ' ').toLowerCase();

$rows.show().filter(function() {
    var text = $(this).text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ').toLowerCase();
    return !~text.indexOf(val);
}).hide();
});
</script>
```

Comment: I think you should put `</tbody></table>` outside of your while loop.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Filter results based on the select box selected value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21385067/filter-results-based-on-the-select-box-selected-value)